# Node.contains() does not detect grandchildren as truthy

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an HTML element of something like this

```
<div class="grand-parent">
  <div class="immediate-parent">
    <div class="grand-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, whenever I'm tring to check

```
const grandchild = document.querySelector(".grand-child");
const grandparent = document.querySelector(".grand-parent");
console.log(grandparent.contains(grandchild));
```

I always get a falsy value returned. I'm running my code on Google Chrome 63.0.3239.84

Comment: You have a typo: it should be `<div class="immediate-parent">`, but you have `<div class="immediate-parent>` (without closing double quote), it's because your HTML is invalid for now. Fix it and `Node.contains()` will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @CommercialSuicide actually that was my typo when I was writing the question. This is just a simplified version of my code for demonstration purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there any multiple `.grand-parent` elements,
or `.grand-child` elements?

querySelector ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)) returns first element, so it might happen that you get not-desired `grandchild` or `grandparent` element.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have a problem with your code and your selector is probably not selecting the right element.

Here's proof that it works. I changed it from `class` to `id` to ensure I'm targeting the right element. Run the code snippet and see for yourself.

```js
const grandchild = document.getElementById("grand-child");
const grandparent = document.getElementById("grand-parent");
console.log(grandparent.contains(grandchild));
```

```html
<div id="grand-parent">
  <div id="immediate-parent">
    <div id="grand-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```